# What is actually spring Reactor Context?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

In non-reactive java we use ThreadLocal to pass Context data, but for Reactor, Spring team recommends using Reactor Context to propagate data to threads.
In spring documentation it says:

**Project Reactor introduced a mechanism that is well aligned with functional programming to provide means to transport contextual metadata. It is simply called Context. And it stays attached to the reactive chain, despite Thread switches that happen behind the scenes.**

I am trying to understand how Reactor Context is actually working. Is it still a ThreadLocal that is just propagated to each thread in this flow or something else?

Answer (score 1):

In Reactor, the Context is essentially a key-value store that "travels" with the reactive sequence.